# Does Anyone Know Of A Basic Java Socket Upload Script For Images?

Tags: java, image, sockets, upload

I'm SOO close to finishing a pet project, this is the last part I need before I'm off to the races and can do without assistance at all. I feel so excited and muzzled at the same time because my needs to interact with the client side have slowed me down for weeks.

Is there a way to upload images without forwarding them to a script or putting my ftp details in my class? The last bit is just plain frightening to me when the host I'm on won't allow me to keep any sensitive files above root. So can a direct client -> server socket connect do the job I want?

Oh,I'm in noviceville when it comes to adding anything to jdk so a native approach on how I could go about this would be most helpful ^_^ Thanks.

---

I'm so confused :'(

I need a dummies guide or something, a lot of this stuff automatically assumes one has a veteran understanding of the java language. I wouldn't mind taking the time to learn from the ground up, but I just don't have the time right now. I'm up to my neck in a PHP project and this is sending it into overtime and affecting my personal life. T_T

How do I found out what are the most suitable ports to listen on btw? Can I make the client/server function in one script for an applet?

Anybody know of a place that explains this all better to a layman?

Even sample code looks like something out of a textbook to me, and they usually don't make for good primers.

Comment: The best thing you can do is keep chipping away at the problem until you can break it down into more manageable bits. Then, ask for help here as you tackle these problems individually if needed. As is, this is really too broad for a Q&A format. We're here to help, but we handle one topic at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a regular socket. Then you can get the output stream and make an `ObjectOutputStream` from it. Just send over the image with that.

Here is an official tutorial on how to use Sockets and Server Sockets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/